How to delay sensor event listener [accelerometer sensor value sampling]?
I apologise if the title isn't clear enough, but I essentially want to be able to sample sensor data only every few seconds. I use accelerometer and GPS sensors.
All my attempts to add delays to the output do not work. A couple of my attempts are included below. I have little to no idea as to why they are not working.

Using countdown timer inside a while(true) loop. The while loop is never entered. I tested using debug/print statements and other simple methods.

        while(true)
        {
            new CountDownTimer(2000, 500)
            {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l)
                {      
                }

                public void onFinish()
                {
                    sensorWork();  // -> Only printing the sensor values. Slightly different from the one included below.
                }
            }.start();
        }


Playing around with listener events. I tried playing around with registering listeners, unregistering them and so on. But the countdown timer seems to work only on first entry.

    public void sensorWork()
    {
        new CountDownTimer(2000, 500)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) 
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

                        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {
                            workLinearAcceleration(sensorEvent);
                        }
                        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY) {
                            workGravity(sensorEvent);
                        }
                        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
                            workGyroscope(sensorEvent);
                        }
                        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
                            workRotationVector(sensorEvent);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
                    }
                };

                sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorGravity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorLinearAcc, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorGyro, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorRotationVector, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

                sensorWork();
            }
        }.start();
    }

My need - Read accelerometer and GPS values every X seconds and print them (print includes printing to UI and saving to a file).
What I can do so far - Get hundreds of accelerometer values every second (too much that block TextView scrolling action) without my intervention; Get GPS values whenever I wish to get them (as intended).
What I need help with - How to get accelerometer values only when I want them? Ideally, I want to be able to set up a countdown timer inside an infinite loop which includes statements to print/save accelerometer and GPS values.

"I essentially want to be able to sample sensor data only every few seconds" -- register the listener. Have the listener do nothing other than cache the last-seen value. Have your every-few-seconds code read that cached last-seen value and use it.
